# how do i ignore/use a carriage return in android

Tags: android, textview, newline

I am attempting to collect data from a user in the form of an edittext.  The user will input a string and click a button to perform the action below:

```
public String encode(String s){
String result = "";
String element = "";

HashMap<String, String> translate = new HashMap<String, String>();

//initializing translate
translate.put("A",".-");
translate.put("B","-...");
translate.put("C","-.-.");
translate.put("D","-..");
translate.put("E",".");
translate.put("F","..-.");
translate.put("G","--.");
translate.put("H","....");
translate.put("I","..");
translate.put("J",".---");
translate.put("K","-.-");
translate.put("L",".-..");
translate.put("M","--");
translate.put("N","-.");
translate.put("O","---");
translate.put("P",".--.");
translate.put("Q","--.-");
translate.put("R",".-.");
translate.put("S","...");
translate.put("T","-");
translate.put("U","..-");
translate.put("V","...-");
translate.put("W",".--");
translate.put("X","-..-");
translate.put("Y","-.--");
translate.put("Z","--..");
translate.put("1",".----");
translate.put("2","..---");
translate.put("3","...--");
translate.put("4","....-");
translate.put("5",".....");
translate.put("6","-....");
translate.put("7","--...");
translate.put("8","---..");
translate.put("9","----.");
translate.put("0","-----");

    s = s.toUpperCase();
    for(int i=0; i < s.length();i++)
        {
        element = (String) translate.get(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
        if(element == null)
            result += String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
        else
            result += element;
        }
    return result;
}
```

If the user hits "enter" on the keyboard of the phone it will insert a newline / carriage return.  How can I address this so that it does add a new line?  I wouldn't mind using the carriage return as a way to issue the command to change focus OUT OF the edittext area, but if not that then just not allow it to be used at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `android:singleLine="true"` in your EditText's XML tag, like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
/>
```

This will make the enter button change the focus to the next view in your UI, rather than inserting a new line in your EditText.

Answer (score 2):

I would put this in the comments but I think my reputation is still not high enough to add comments.

Since android:singleLine="true" is now deprecated, another option is to use android:inputType="text". It's a slight change to @Tiago_Pasqualini's answer:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
/>
```

This too will make the enter button change focus to the next view in the UI and skip entering a new line into the EditText.